# Is there a way to make nautilus display the "recently used" files and directories?

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3, nautilus

**Is there a way to make nautilus display the "recently used" files and directories, just like the "open file" dialog does?**

Just to make my question clearer, here are two screenshots:

**The GTK open file dialog, showing the recently used items:**

[image: recently used]

**A nautilus window, which doesn't offer to display recently used items:**

[image: nautilus]

**EDIT** : This has been [added as a feature request to Nautilus](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325824). Don't hesitate to make your voice heard if you want it to happen!

Comment: BGO bug #325824 has been marked fixed. Change will presumably appear in GNOME 3.6 http://blogs.gnome.org/commitdigest/2012/07/15/issue-197/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such thing as "recently used" in Nautilus. There is however GTK feature called "Recent Documents", which you may find in Gnome menu `Places -> Recent Documents`. To implement it in Nautilus will require the use of `GtkRecentManager/GtkRecentChooser`

I don't know, why they included it in the open file dialog, but not in Nautilus. `GtkRecentChooser` is Gtk+ stuff, not Gnome, so any Gtk+ application supports it by default (like in open file dialog). You're right it's intuitive, that Nautilus should have this feature too. Suggest a new feature, maybe? http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=nautilus

Answer (score 1):

You definitely know that, but for the sake of completeness - the `Go` menu of Nautilus window has the list of locations you recently visited. However, recently accessed files aren't added there - only directories.

So you may navigate to recent files with `Places -> Recent Documents` (just as sindikat [suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/344446/is-there-a-way-to-make-nautilus-display-the-recently-used-files-and-directories/345219#345219)), and to recent directories with `Go -> directory_name`.

Comment: What distro and version of Gnome do you use? On GNOME 3.2 on my machine, the Go menu definitely doesn't have this list. Nor do I have a "places" menu, btw.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the 'gnome3' tag - I'm on Debian/Gnome 2.30.2. In 3.2, those items might be called "History" or something like that (I don't currently have access to any Gnome 3.2 machines). Quick DDGoing hints that "Places" might now be an extension to Gnome3.